# How do I reduce an Object to a new Object with multiple key:value pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
90: {month: "06", context: "-", year: "2019", pageLabel: "Zusammenfassung", hits: 18}
91: {month: "06", context: "LiveTest", year: "2019", pageLabel: "Zusammenfassung", hits: 4}
92: {month: "07", context: "-", year: "2019", pageLabel: "Zusammenfassung", hits: 22}
93: {month: "07", context: "LiveTest", year: "2019", pageLabel: "Zusammenfassung", hits: 14}
```

So I'm trying to get a new array of Objects for the specific month which should contain the key value pairs of hits + pageLabel. But i only managed to get an Array of Objects with the hits.

```
var output = LIVE_STAT_DATA.reduce(function(o, cur){

        var occurs = o.reduce(function(n, item, i) {
            return (item.month === cur.month) ? i:n;
        },-1);

        if(occurs >=0 ){
            //füge den aktuellen hits, der liste von hits hinzu
            o[occurs].hits = o[occurs].hits.concat(cur.hits);

        }else{
            var obj = {
                month: cur.month,
                hits: [cur.hits],

            };
            o = o.concat([obj]);
        }

        return o;
    }, []);

    console.log("months + hits + pageLabel",output);
```

This is the result:

```
0:
month: "06"
hits: (26) [6, 50, 34, 4, 36, 4, 24, 4, 22, 4, 34, 4, 26, 4, 20, 6, 22, 4, 18, 4, 14, 10, 10, 4, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve] then tell us what you expected as output

Comment: Can you introduce [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) and use groupBy? If you can do so you can simply do: `output= _.groupBy(LIVE_STAT_DATA, 'month');` and then use just a `map`.

Comment: @Doni, welcome to SO. I think, though I confess I am coming up with this off the top of my head, your issue lies in `var obj = { month: cur.month, hits: [cur.hits], }; o = o.concat([obj]);`. Using `{}` is initializing another object  with current month ans hits. If I read your question correctly you want an array returned. I would first define an array, `var a = new Array();` then push your values into it: `a.push([month, hits])`. Again purely off the top of my head. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution would be something like this

```js
const arr = [
  {month: "06", context: "-", year: "2019", pageLabel: "Zusammenfassung", hits: 18},
  {month: "06", context: "LiveTest", year: "2019", pageLabel: "Zusammenfassung", hits: 4},
  {month: "07", context: "-", year: "2019", pageLabel: "Zusammenfassung", hits: 22},
  {month: "07", context: "LiveTest", year: "2019", pageLabel: "Zusammenfassung", hits: 14}
];

const fct = (arr, month) => {
  return arr.filter(obj =>
    obj.month == month
  ).map(obj => ({
    pageLabel: obj.pageLabel,
    hits: obj.hits
  }));
}

console.log(fct(arr,"06"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

use filter to get all objects with month == "06" for example, then map through the  array and extract the keys you want explicitly like this